# Difference between RoundRobinRouter and RoundRobinRoutinglogic

Tags: scala, akka

So I was reading tutorial about akka and came across this http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2014/04/23/a-handful-akka-techniques/ and I think he explained it pretty well, I just picked up scala recently and having difficulties with the tutorial above,

I wonder what is the difference between RoundRobinRouter and the current RoundRobinRouterLogic? Obviously the implementation is quite different.

Previously the implementation of RoundRobinRouter is

```
val workers = context.actorOf(Props[ItemProcessingWorker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(100)))
```

with processBatch

```
 def processBatch(batch: List[BatchItem]) = {

    if (batch.isEmpty) {
      log.info(s"Done migrating all items for data set $dataSetId. $totalItems processed items, we had ${allProcessingErrors.size} errors in total")
    } else {
      // reset processing state for the current batch
      currentBatchSize = batch.size
      allProcessedItemsCount = currentProcessedItemsCount + allProcessedItemsCount
      currentProcessedItemsCount = 0
      allProcessingErrors = currentProcessingErrors ::: allProcessingErrors
      currentProcessingErrors = List.empty

      // distribute the work
      batch foreach { item =>
        workers ! item
      }
    }

  }
```

Here's my implementation of RoundRobinRouterLogic

```
  var mappings : Option[ActorRef] = None

  var router = {
    val routees = Vector.fill(100) {
      mappings = Some(context.actorOf(Props[Application3]))
      context watch mappings.get
      ActorRefRoutee(mappings.get)
    }
    Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
  }
```

and treated the processBatch as such

```
 def processBatch(batch: List[BatchItem]) = {

    if (batch.isEmpty) {
      println(s"Done migrating all items for data set $dataSetId. $totalItems processed items, we had ${allProcessingErrors.size} errors in total")
    } else {
      // reset processing state for the current batch
      currentBatchSize = batch.size
      allProcessedItemsCount = currentProcessedItemsCount + allProcessedItemsCount
      currentProcessedItemsCount = 0
      allProcessingErrors = currentProcessingErrors ::: allProcessingErrors
      currentProcessingErrors = List.empty

      // distribute the work
      batch foreach { item => 
        // println(item.id)            
        mappings.get ! item
      }
    }
  }
```

I somehow cannot run this tutorial, and it's stuck at the point where it's iterating the batch list. I wonder what I did wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I misunderstood the method, and found out the solution was to use RoundRobinPool as stated in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3-M2/project/migration-guide-2.2.x-2.3.x.html

> For example RoundRobinRouter has been renamed to RoundRobinPool or
>   RoundRobinGroup depending on which type you are actually using.

from

```
val workers = context.actorOf(Props[ItemProcessingWorker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(100)))
```

to

```
val workers = context.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(100).props(Props[ItemProcessingWorker]), "router2")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, you have to distinguish diff between them.

`RoundRobinRouter` is a Router that uses round-robin to select a connection.

While
`RoundRobinRoutingLogic` uses round-robin to select a routee

You can provide own RoutingLogic (it has helped me to understand how Akka works under the hood)

```
class RedundancyRoutingLogic(nbrCopies: Int) extends RoutingLogic {
  val roundRobin = RoundRobinRoutingLogic()
  def select(message: Any, routees: immutable.IndexedSeq[Routee]): Routee = {
    val targets = (1 to nbrCopies).map(_ => roundRobin.select(message, routees))
    SeveralRoutees(targets)
  }
}
```

link on doc http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.3/scala/routing.html
p.s. this doc is very clear and it has helped me the most

Comment: Thanks :) Art_Rebel

Comment: if it was helpful, please mark this post as answered, please.

Comment: Marked it as useful, I was looking for the substitute implementation for RoundRobinRouter :)